# How much time to find satisfying values of $\Pi_2$ theorems of Robinson arithmetic?

Tags: computational-complexity, first-order-logic

As far as I can tell, for any $\Pi_2$ theorem of Robinson arithmetic

$\forall_{x_1,\dots,x_m} \exists_{y_1,\dots,y_n} P(x_1,\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_n)$

where $P$ is quantifier-free, there is a subexponential-time algorithm to find $y_1,\dots,y_n$ given $x_1,\dots,x_m$.  A counterexample would be the sentence $\forall_x \exists_y (2^x = y)$, expressed using the $\beta$ function — since the size of the output is exponential in the size of the input it can't be computed by a subexponential-time ($x^{o(1)}$) algorithm.  But I understand it's not a theorem since Robinson arithmetic can't prove $2^x$ is total, that would require induction.

Is this true?  Or can Robinson arithmetic prove sentences whose satisfying values can't be found in subexponential time?